# How to view the values of a tensor and perform indexing on tensors when using Keras with Theano backend?

Tags: python, numpy, keras, neural-network, theano

I'm trying to reproduce a network where points in the embedded space (of the autoencoder) need to be updated between each batch using Keras with a Theano backend.  For the network to work, it needs to perform updates to the network weights in between each batch.  The loss function is from the paper "Towards K-means Friendly Spaces."

Since I have to update the network weights in between each batch, I do this for every batch (update the network for one batch, then update embedded space before next batch):

```
loss = self.model.train_on_batch(x=self.images[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size],
                                             y = [self.images[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]])

self.latent_features = self.model.get_layer(name='embedding').output
self._cluster_distsqs = K.sum(K.square(self.latent_features - self.centroids), axis=2)
self._assigns = K.argmin(self._cluster_distsqs, axis=1)
for i in range(batch_size):
    assign = self._assigns[i]
    count = self.centroid_counts[assign]
    centroid = self.centroids[assign]
    feature = self.latent_features[i]

        if cnt>1:
           new_centroid = centroid - (1.0 / cnt) * (centroid - feature)
           self.centroids[:,assign,:] = new_centroid
        else:   
            self.centroid_counts[assign] = cnt+1
```

Essentially, I need to get the values of the tensors at various points and this needs to be done via performing indexing.  Ive tried K.get_value(assign), K.eval(assign), K.print_tensor(assign), but nothing seems to let me access the actual value of the tensor.  I've tried this for other tensors too, and I always get TensorVariable, Subtensor(Int64).0, or something along the lines.  Can anyone help me perform this whether if its by converting to numpy arrays or converting all to tensors or another method all together?  Thank you very much!

Comment: The actual value only exists during the training pass. This means everything is concealed inside `train_on_batch`. 

In order to do this you will need to pass the desired tensors to the loss function and use some `K.update` or similar on the tensors you want to update. This will only work inside a Lambda layer or inside the loss function, and will happen necessarily before weights are adjusted by backpropagation.

Comment: The development of Theano is discontinued. Is there any specific reason you are using it?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @Daniel Moller.  I was not aware of this.  I moved the code below train_on_batch into my custom_loss function.  I also changed the self.centroids, self.assigns, etc to (object_name).centroids, (object_name).assigns, etc.  However, even with this method, I get the same error.     '''IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices'''

Comment: @MathiasMüller Yes early on when I was using Tensorflow as a backend, I ran into an error about Tensor object not having an attribute ndim.  This was apparently solvable by switching to Theano backend, which I did.

Comment: If moving to tensorflow is an option, certainly do it. You'd go with `keras.backend.shape(tensor)` to get the shape of a tensor as a tensor, or `keras.backend.int_shape(tensor)` to get the shape of a tensor as a tuple of integers (may contain `None` values)

Comment: "Yes early on when I was using Tensorflow as a backend, I ran into an error about Tensor object not having an attribute ndim." - this must have been years ago. Perhaps you should give it another try :-).